# Printing the power set of a given set of elements

Tags: java, strings, set

- Input: Set of elements (`String`)
- Output: Printing the elements of the power set of the given set

```
public class PrintPowerSet {
public static List<String> permuteSet(String inputSet){

    List<String> powerSet = new ArrayList<String>();
    int n = inputSet.length(); //size for binary

    for(int i=0;i<Math.pow(2,n);i++){
        if(i==0){
            powerSet.add("Ø"); //empty set Case
            continue;
        }
        String binaryOfIndex = getBinaryString(i, n);
        StringBuffer subset = new StringBuffer();
        for(int j=0;j<binaryOfIndex.length();j++){
            if(binaryOfIndex.charAt(j)=='1'){
                subset.append(inputSet.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        powerSet.add(subset.toString());
    }
    return powerSet;
}

public static String getBinaryString(int i, int size) {
    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    bin = String.format("%0" + size + "d", Integer.parseInt(bin));
    return bin;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    String set = "gle";
    List<String> result;
    result = permuteSet(set);
    for(String word: result){
        System.out.print(word+" ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The integer to string to integer representation of string to string conversion is very wasteful. You can just do bit shifts.

```
private static String getSubset(String inputSet, int mask) {
    StringBuffer subset = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputSet.length(); i++) {
        // Check if ith bit is set
        if ((mask & (1 << i)) != 0) {
            subset.append(inputSet.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return subset.toString();
}

public static List<String> permuteSet(String inputSet) {
    List<String> powerSet = new ArrayList<String>();
    int n = inputSet.length(); // size for binary
    int powerSetLength = 1 << n; // you should check that n is small enough

    for (int i = 0; i < powerSetLength; i++) {
        powerSet.add(getSubset(inputSet, i));
    }

    return powerSet;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/nlQk28)